# Basic file upload - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, html, cpanel

Just playing around with uploading files as it's actually something I've never done before. I copied some supposedly working code from [here](http://davidwalsh.name/basic-file-uploading-php).

I'm using cPanel hosting from Namecheap, with absolutely nothing changed from the default config.

I think the most likely problem is something very basic that I haven't activated. My HTML looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Your Photo: <input type="file" name="photo" size="25" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my PHP looks like this

```
<?php
//if they DID upload a file...
if($_FILES['photo']['name'])
{
    //if no errors...
    if(!$_FILES['photo']['error'])
    {
        //now is the time to modify the future file name and validate the file
        $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); //rename file
        if($_FILES['photo']['size'] > (1024000)) //can't be larger than 1 MB
        {
            $valid_file = false;
            $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
        }

        //if the file has passed the test
        if($valid_file)
        {
            //move it to where we want it to be
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$new_file_name);
            $message = 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';
        }
    }
    //if there is an error...
    else
    {
        //set that to be the returned message
        $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['photo']['error'];
    }
}

//you get the following information for each file:
$_FILES['field_name']['name']
$_FILES['field_name']['size']
$_FILES['field_name']['type']
$_FILES['field_name']['tmp_name']
}
```

When I try to upload an image, I get a 500 Internal Server Error when I hit submit.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your webserver error logs? If you have error logging enabled (should be by default) it will contain the error message,file and line number where it failed

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the stuff at the bottom:

```
<?php
//if they DID upload a file...
if($_FILES['photo']['name'])
{
    //if no errors...
    if(!$_FILES['photo']['error'])
    {
        //now is the time to modify the future file name and validate the file
        $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); //rename file
        if($_FILES['photo']['size'] > (1024000)) //can't be larger than 1 MB
        {
            $valid_file = false;
            $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
        }

        //if the file has passed the test
        if($valid_file)
        {
            //move it to where we want it to be
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$new_file_name);
            $message = 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';
        }
    }
    //if there is an error...
    else
    {
        //set that to be the returned message
        $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['photo']['error'];
    }

}
```

Not sure what that was for... Also, try checking the Namecheap php.ini in your CPanel to see what the max upload size is so your users get your error, not a PHP error or a 500.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Only problem I'm having is I can't figure out where it's putting the images. 

From the code it looks like they'd be in /uploads/ relative to upload_file.php, but nothing appears there despite permissions being correct.

Comment: @Sam what about putting an if or die error on the move_uploaded_file?